# How to change width and height dynamically with leveling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have faced some problems. When I write text on a input field, writing text show another text filed. Another text field width and height not changing dynamically with leveling like below image and demo site

[My Demo Site](http://www.knowledgediarybd.com/iluma/)

Default width and height

[image: Default Width Height]

[image: Not Change level and height and width]

[image: Input Field]

But I want like this desired output
[Desired Output Link](http://www.skyltdirect.se/sso/index.php)

[image: desired output]

[image: desired output]

For desired output input like these and Demo Site

[image: input]

I have faced another problem height is shown upper of the box. But the height  should show left or right position of the box.

Inner hole of the box is another problem that i don't include my box.

And last problem is don't add leveling end arrow of the leveling line. My code is below

For input text

```
<div class="text_input1">
    <p class="label1"> Text 1 <input class="input_box1" type="text" id="text11" name="text11" value="Enter Text1"></p>
</div>

 <div class="text_input1">
<p class="label1"> Text 2 <input class="input_box1" type="text" id="text22" name="text22" value="Enter Text2"></p>
</div>

<div class="text_input1">
<p class="label1"> Text 3 <input class="input_box1" type="text" id="text33" name="text33" value="Enter Text3"></p>
</div>
```

For width and height Select

```
</div>

<h2 class="shape_text_width">WIDTH:</h2>
<div class="iteam_icon2">

<input type="text" id="width" name="width" value="79" onchange="XX()"><p class="mili1">mm</p</input>

</div>
<h2 class="shape_text_width">HEIGHT:</h2>
<div class="iteam_icon2">

    <input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="26" onchange="XX1()"><p class="mili1">mm</p></input>

</div>
```

Change width and height

```
$( "#width_label" ).text(79 + " mm");
$("#height_label" ).text( 26 + " mm");

function XX()
{
    var first2 =document.getElementById("width").value;
      var width=first2;
      var width_in_px=width*3.779527559;
      var total_width = Math.round(width_in_px);
      var f_width_in_px = parseInt(total_width);

      var mm_text="mm";

      $('#mySVG1').css("width", f_width_in_px + "px");
      $('#shape1').css("width", f_width_in_px + "px");
      $( "#width_label" ).text( width + " mm");
      $('#width_label').css("width", f_width_in_px + "px");

      var dif=width-300;
      if(width>300)
      {
      $('#height_label').css("margin-right", dif + "px");
      }

} 

 function XX1()
{
    var first22 =document.getElementById("height").value;


      var height=first22;
      var height_in_px=height*3.779527559;
      var total_height = Math.round(height_in_px);
      var f_height_in_px = parseInt(total_height);

      $('#mySVG1').css("height", f_height_in_px + "px");
      $('#shape1').css("height", f_height_in_px + "px");
      $("#height_label" ).text( height + " mm");
      $('#height_label').css("width", f_height_in_px + "px");

}
```

My OutPut field box width, height and output text code is below

```
<div class="label_fix" id="height_label" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   width:100px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   padding: 2px;">
</div>

<svg  style="width:300px;height:100px" id="mySVG1">
     <rect id="shape1" x="0" y="0" style="width:300px;height:100px" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" fill="white"/>
     <<text id="text1" x="50%" y="25%" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"></text> 
     <<text id="text2" x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"></text> 
     <<text id="text3" x="50%" y="75%" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"></text> 

</svg>

<div class="label_fix" id="width_label" style="border-top: 1px solid #000;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 5px;
   padding: 2px;">
</div>
```

Value Add to my output field

```
<script>
$( "#text11" )
  .keyup(function(test1) {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#text1" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_second_1" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_third_1" ).text( value );

  })
</script>
<script>
$( "#text22" )
  .keyup(function(test2) {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#text2" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_second_2" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_third_2" ).text( value );

  })
</script>
<script>
$( "#text33" )
  .keyup(function(test3) {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#text3" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_second_3" ).text( value );
    $( "#text_third_3" ).text( value );

  })
</script>
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code down to your problem and I will try to help you. Are you trying to create a template generator or you just want the output result? If the output is what you are looking for, it can be easily created using pure css.

Comment: I need only ouput and I explain my problem above. If you go to 'My demo site' and 'Desired output link' then you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment remark above, here is what you are looking after in pure css. Since the one you asked for required the image to be in mm, I tried to keep the correct ratio using px, however, it is up to you to adjust values as you see fit to get the produced results.

All you need is a `div` and the following style. To fake the 'holes' I applied a background color to the body and used the same color to color the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

```
body {
  background:#ccc;
}
.box {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#fff;
  width:99px;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:7px 0;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
  font-size:14px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  display:block;
  width:8px;
  height:8px;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.box:after {
  left:auto;
  right:5px;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/s6r6frgx/2/

Comment: when I use as input "<div class="box">Stack<br>over<br>Flow</div>" then it goes out the box area

Comment: It's almost fine what i desired but  I am glad if width is adjusted dynamically also.

Comment: I initially thought that fixed width and height were required. Here is an even-more-updated jsfiddle to suit your needs https://jsfiddle.net/s6r6frgx/3/

Comment: It's fine. Thanks a lot